# problem related email application

Tags: iphone

I want to send an email from my application whenever a user taps the SEND button of my view.I do not want to show the email interface to the user.All the fields needed for email will we filled via my application.So is there anyway to do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a project on Google Code called [skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) which will allow you to send off a faceless email.

Alternatively you could have a look at the [Pantomime](http://www.collaboration-world.com/pantomime) package. It also contains implementations of the SMTP protocol. It has however not (yet) been ported to iPhone AFAIK, but since it's written in Cocoa it should not be that big a task for doing this specifically for the SMTP part..